# Triggering Angular change detection in ngOnChanges (so css animations are restarted)

Tags: angular, animation, angular2-changedetection, angular-changedetection

Let's say I have a very basic component that takes a number as an input and renders it (e.g. a stock price value). When that number increases, or decreases from its previous value, an animation should show for 10 seconds and then disappear. If the input value changes during this 10 seconds, the animation should restart, and hide after 10 seconds (or restart yet again if the value changes again, etc).

I've implemented this for my use case using basic css keyframe animations. Perhaps this is the wrong approach, but it is easier than having to get to grips with the angular animations library.

I've setup the obligatory stackblitz example to illustrate my issue. If you click the increment or decrement button, wait for the bouncing to stop, and then click that button again, the animation doesn't restart.

I have solved this by using a `setTimeout(() => {...}, 100)` when changing the animation "back to true" (lines 26-33 of hello.component.ts), but this is obviously not the angular way to do this.

Any guidance would be appreciated.

edit: forgot stackblitz link: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-u9ogwv

Comment: where is stackblitz  link ?

Comment: DOH! Sorry, added it.